# Can I launch mysqlfrm.exe from workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to get the 'CREATE statement' of a table from a .frm file (that comes from a corrupted HD, so I don't have anything else to recover my table).

But, when I try to launch it, by clicking 2 times on it, it closes itself immediately.

Is there a way to launch it from workbench, or another way to get a create statement from a .frm file?